# To find out the number of occruence of words in a file

Tags: c#, .net

I came across this question in an interview:

We have to find out the number of occurences of two given words in a text file with `<=n` words between them.

Example1:

```
text:`this is first string this is second string`  
Keywords:`this, string`  
n= 4  
output= 2
```

"**this** is first **string**" is the *first* occurrence and number of words between this and string is 2(is, first) which is less than 4.

**this** is second **string** is the remaining string. number of words between **this and string ** is 2 (is, second) which is less than 4.

Therefore the answer is 2.

I have thought that I will use 
    `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`.

My idea was that I use the dictionary and get the list of places where the particular word is repeated and then iterate through both the lists, increment the count if a condition is met and then display the count.

Is my thinking process correct? Please provide any suggestions to improve my solution.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: The word `links` does not appear in the first example. The output should be `0`.

Comment: @ downvoter. Please care to comment.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer per-se (as quite honestly, I don't understand the question :P), but to add some general interview advice to the other answers:

In interviews the interviewer is always looking for the thought process and that you are a critical, logical thinker. Not necessarily that you have excellent coding recall and can compile code in your brain.

In addition interviews are a stressful process. By slowing down and talking out loud as you work things out you not only look like a better communicator and logical thinker (even if getting the question wrong), you also give yourself time to think.

Use a pen and paper, speak as you think, start off from the top and work through it. I've got jobs even if I didn't know the answers to tech questions by demonstrating that I can at least try to work things out ;-)

In short, it's not just down to technical prowess

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends if the call is done only one or multiple times per string. If it's something like

```
int getOccurences(String str, String reference, int min_size) { ... }
```

then you don't really need the dictionary, not even a ist. You can just iterate through the string to find occurrences of words and then check the number of separators between them.

If on the other hand the problem is for arbitrary search/indexing, IMHO you do need a dictionary. I'd go for a dictionary where the key is the word and the value is a list of indexes where it occurs.

HTH

Comment: The input text is given in a text file.

Comment: Hmm. it doesn't change the above solution too much. Instead of "str" you'll have the file name. You can choose to read it all at once or buffer it (if it's too big).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that repeatedly for different pairs of words in the same text, then a word dictionary with a list of indexes is a good solution. However, if you were only looking for one pair, then two lists of indexes for those two words would be sufficient.

The lists allow you to separate the word detection operation from the counting logic.